# &nbsp jsx not working

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am using the &nbsp tag in jsx and it is not rendering the space. The following is a small snippet of my code.Please help.

```
var Reporting=React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return(
      <div style={divPositionReporting}>
          <p>Pricing Reports</p>
          <hr></hr>
          Select Scenario:&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select>
            <option></option>
          </select>
          <button type="button">Get Pricing Report</button>
          <br/>
          Select Takeout Scenario:&nbsp;
          <select>
            <option></option>
          </select>
          <button type="button">Get Pricing Report</button>
          <br/>
      </div>
    );
  },

});
```

Comment: Did you search? First hit: https://www.google.com/search?q=react+html+entities

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. Which Babel and React version are using? Make sure to use the latest versions. You can see in the [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=react) that the generated code contains non-breaking whitespace characters.

Comment: Well now the first hit is this. :) https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jsx+nbsp

Comment: Now the first hit is an equivalent question here on SO, but asked a year later  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116800/how-to-show-html-entity-using-react

Comment: Eight years later: the first Google hit for "nbsp jsx" ([https://google.com/search?q=nbsp+jsx](https://google.com/search?q=nbsp+jsx)) is now this Stack Overflow post with people telling OP to Google it.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

See: [JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)

Try: 
`Select Scenario:{'\u00A0'}`

Or:
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'Select Scenario: &nbsp;'}} />`

Or:
`<div>&nbsp;</div>`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/b4st33nw/)

### Update

After seeing some of the comments, and trying it out. It has come to my attention that using html entites inside JSX works fine (unlike what is stated in the above jsx-gotchas reference [maybe it's outdated]).

So using something like: `R&amp;D`, would output: 'R&D'. 
There is a weird behavior with `&nbsp;`, which causes it to render differently, thus causing me to think it doesn't work:

```
<div>This works simply:-&nbsp;-</div>
<div>This works simply:- {'\u00A0'}-</div>
```

Produces:

```
This works simply:- -
This works simply:-  -
```

Comment: So the answer is using the unicode value corresponding to the html entity and using it inside a javascript string.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IndraneelBende `&nbsp;` should work fine. There is some problem with the value in style attribute.

Comment: @Gaurav Kumar, I also tried didn't work, it is just ignored. Could you please add to the fiddle in my answer?

Comment: `<div>Doesn't work: -&nbsp;-</div>` works just fine for me. *edit:* Well, it doesn't seem to be a non-breaking space.

Comment: Mmh, produces the expected output on the React website itself though...

Comment: Maybe on React site they have wrapped it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, or something

Comment: I could imagine it's an issue with the Babel version jsfiddle is using. Babel v6.9.1. Copy your code [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=).

Comment: @omerts check this. https://jsfiddle.net/rickgaurav/hofp8w66/. Also in your fiddle the second Doesn't work line work fine if u see closely.

Comment: @GauravKumar Look at the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/hofp8w66/2/. It caused me to think it doesn't work. I tried other entites, and you are right, they did work, edited my answer.

Comment: @omerts look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/rickgaurav/sfehkL1y/  . I have made changes to your fiddle to fix issue with your code. Also for string interpolation in ES6 operator `\`` is used , not `'` . Anyways there was no need to for any interpolation as it is itself a character not a variable.

Comment: @GauravKumar I still see a difference: https://s32.postimg.org/jcu3s26fp/space.jpg

Comment: To clarify... 
\u00A0
works because it is the Unicode character "NO-BREAK SPACE". So you can pass it around in a JavaScript string, and then when it is output, it works like
&nbsp;

Comment: Better to use it inside react fragment, `<>&nbsp;</>`

Comment: It's worth noting that `u00A0` is being blacklisted by browsers due to phishing schemes. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.IDN.blacklist_chars

Comment: @AndrewHill this document is about domain names, what's the relation to JSX/HTML?

Answer (score 47):

`{'\u00A0'}` works but is hard to read, so I wrapped it in a [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

components/nbsp.js:

```
export default () => '\u00A0';
```

usage:

```
Hello<Nbsp />world
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well! FWIW it may also be used in a template literal like `const h = \` Hello${Nbsp()}world\`; ... <span>{h}</span>`

Answer (score 20):

You could simply wrap it with `Fragment`:

`<Fragment>&nbsp;</Fragment>`

Comment: You can even simplify it by using: `<>&nbsp;</>`

Answer (score 19):

Write your `jsx` code wrapped in `{` `}` as shown below.

```
<h1>Code {' '}</h1>
```

You can put space or any special character here.

e.g in your case

```
Select Takeout Scenario:&nbsp;
```

should be like this

```
Select Takeout Scenario:{' '}
```

It will work.

As Advice you should not use `&nbsp` to add extra space, you can use **css** to achieve same.

Comment: This is just to add whitespace, but won't work for other html entities

Comment: That not a *non-breaking* space though.

Comment: @TimoSolo I do not encourage you to use &nbsp or above mentioned technique. You can try the first answer if mine is not working. Thanks.

Comment: "use css to achieve same" - You might be using non breaking space so your text does not drop down to the next line and outside the boundary of the element which contains the text. If you want to use CSS properties to do this instead, then one way to do this is `text-overflow: "clip";` `overflow: "hidden";`. There are a few variations available.

Answer (score 11):

If this doesn't work for you `{' '}` then use `{'\u00A0'}`.

`{' '}` will render a space but there are some cases when you want the line height to also be rendered in a case there you want a space inside an HTML element that has no other text ie: `<span style={{ lineHeight: '1em' }}>{' '}</span>`, in that case you'll need to use `{'\u00A0'}` inside the span or HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

I used    `<span>&nbsp;</span>`    and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use utf-8 nbsp, seem as simple space, but working good without extra code.

Maybe, you should create variable for this.

For copy symbols:
https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/

For generate texts automatically, use some typograf.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest is `<>&nbsp;</>`

Comment: except it's not the shortest

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use CSS when manipulating JSX with white space. It's a better approach and has a good deal with string type when the value includes many white spaces.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('     hello            white space  !');
  return (
    <p style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{text}</p>
  )
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across these solutions while searching for similar solution for REACT NATIVE. The solution {' '} works fine. Interesting also to note that the length of space can be widened by increasing the length within the single quote.
For REACTJS,  the best approach for me is css and `<span style={stylename}></span>`
The stylename will mainly set the right or left margin whichever one prefers

Answer (score -2):

You can also use ES6 template literals i.e.,

```
`   <li></li>` or `  ${value}`
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with html entities?