# How to show html entity using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, superscript

I am wanting to show the 'cubic' html entity (superscript 3). I am doing like 
 this:

```
const formatArea = function(val){
    return val + " ft&sup3;";
}
```

where `formatArea` is being called from inside the component':

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {formatArea(this.props.area)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

but, the browser is showing it as `ft&sup3;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found this way using JSX:

```
const formatArea = (val) => {
    return (<span>{val}&nbsp;ft<sup>3</sup></span>);
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Another option is to use [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method:

```
const formatArea = (val) => {
    return val + ' ft' + String.fromCharCode(179);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: easy and clean!

Comment: Took way to long to find this answer. Always used dangerously... even though I really didn't like that. Finally something simple and clean!

Answer (score 43):

New way using React's [fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html):

```
<>&sup3;</>
```

In your case it can be:

```
const formatArea = function(val){
    return <>{val + ' '}&sup3;</>
}
```

Comment: thx, you can also use this with the  ternary operator  e.g. `{ sortOrder === 'asc' ? <> &#x25B2;</> : <> &#x25BC;</> }`

Answer (score 18):

You can get that using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` feature of jsx.

Another way would be use correspond `unicode` character of html entity and just use as normal string.

```js
const formatArea = function(val){
    return val + " ft&sup3;";
}

const Comp = ({text}) => (
<div>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `${text}`}} />
<div>{'53 ft\u00B3'}</div>
</div>

);

ReactDOM.render( <Comp text={formatArea(53)} /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 18):

- Method 1

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft{'³'}</div>`
- Method 2

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft{'\u00B3'}</div>`
- Method 3: [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft{String.fromCharCode(parseInt('B3', 16))}</div>`
- Method 4

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft{String.fromCharCode(179)}</div>`
- Method 5: [HTML Codes](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft&sup3;</div>`
- Method 6

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft&#179;</div>`
- Method 7

  `const formatArea = val => <div>{val} ft<sup>3</sup></div>`

Then you can render it:

```
render() {
  return (
    {formatArea(this.props.area)}
  )
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but the usage is odd. Since this is React wouldn't it make sense to render it as `<FormatArea val={this.props.area} />` And declare those as proper components such as `const FormatArea = ({val})=> <div>{val} ft{'³'}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
const formatArea = function(val){
  return <>{val} ft<span>&sup3;</span></>;
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {formatArea(this.props.area)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wdtifv?file=index.js)