# display html entity Superscript in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

new to react. I am getting a JSON with this value

```
{
"unit": "G/ft&sup2;/yr"
}
```

I am setting it in a state variable and then using it to display in the title.
I have done this in Django before and it converts it properly but I don't see that happening here so. am I sending the data wrong or is there a way to do this.

```
setUnit({
        water_flow_unit: item.unit
      });
```

```
<h4 className="baseline-graph-header">
   Unit({Unit.unit})
</h4>
```

it displays as `G/ft&sup2;/yr` but I want it converted.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want it converted to what? What is `Unit` ?

Comment: @Cristy Its just useState hook. 
const [Unit, setUnit] = useState("")

Comment: Show the rest of your component code.

Comment: @DaminiGanesh it should be [ unit, setUnit ] = ....  and why are you trying to call it as a function in your h4?

Comment: @DaminiGanesh In that case, what is `Unit.unit`, as it's not defined in that hook.

Comment: @GifCo I just have a <div> <h4 className="baseline-graph-header">
            Whole Building Water Flow ({waterUse.water_flow_unit})
          </h4></div>
And its getting the data in the render just not converting the superscript

Comment: Ok while the end of your question it says it outputs (G/ft²/yr) is that not what you want?

Comment: @DaminiGanesh `&sup;` is a HTML entity, you can't show plain HTML in React unless  you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: @Cristy It is defined but there is more data I am setting using the hooks as an object which I can show so I am just should you the method I have used. 
The data in the hook is getting set and is being displayed. I just want it to convert the superscript while displaying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show html entity using React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116800/how-to-show-html-entity-using-react)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found which worked best for me is

```
<span
 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `${Unit.unit})`
   }}
 />
```

Make sure you out it in a span or a div element or else you ll get a --
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__html}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead-- error

refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml