# How can I render JSX tags as text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Had an idea for my portfolio, whereby I would wrap my surname in JSX component tags - JOE  - with the tags as plain old paragraph text within spans, then style. But the tags are obviously being interpreted by my code editor as JSX tags, rather than text, throwing errors.

Does anyone know of an element that would wrap around the tags, rendering them as text? Tried a few things but can't figure it out.

```
<h1> JOE <span className='neon'> < </span> BLOGGS <span className='neon'> /> </span> </h1>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: is [html entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) not working for you?

Comment: Hi thorntj85 and welcome to stack overflow. Just wanted to put this here for any and all of your future questions and I hope it helps you in the long term [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show html entity using React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116800/how-to-show-html-entity-using-react)

Answer (score 3):

To render HTML markup as text you can use [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity). Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`:

```
<h1> JOE <span className='neon'> &lt; </span> BLOGGS <span className='neon'> /&gt; </span> </h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try wrapping it in curly braces `{}`, which denote it as a JavaScript expression

```
  <h1> JOE <span className='neon'> {'<'} </span> BLOGGS <span className='neon'> {'/>'} </span> </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `{'/>'}` to show the characters as text

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use direct `{'<'}`, `{'>'}` as an expression or HTML entities `&lt;`