# How to replace space with &nbsp; in a string (ReactJS) and render in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string, next.js

```
<div className="mt-2 font-sidebar capitalize">
  {item.title}
</div>
```

`item.title` can be any string (from backend) for example "all products", "most liked", "featured items", etc.

I want a way to replace the **space** in `item.title` with `&nbsp;` so that when rendered in HTML it still has a space - This is for a specific use case.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What went wrong when `item.title.replace` was used?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  It directly prints it. Ex: All&nbsp;Products

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show html entity using React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116800/how-to-show-html-entity-using-react)

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox this helped! Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
{item.title.replaceAll(' ', '\u00a0')};
```

you can use `replace()` if you are sure there is only 1 space, so i suggest to use `replaceAll()`

Instead of using the `&nbsp;` you can use the Unicode character which `&nbsp;` refers to (U+00A0):