# html entities not converting special symbols

Tags: html, character-encoding, escaping, express-validator, html-escape-characters

I'm using express-validator to sanitize and escape the inputs from body, the input is **2/1** I sanitize as follows:

```
body("abbreviation")
      .notEmpty()
      .isLength({ min: 2, max: 11 })
      .trim()
      .escape()
      .matches(/[A-Za-z\d ._\-)(\\/]*/)
```

the value stored in Database after sanitizing is `2&#x2F;1`

and when I render the value to front end it shows as the escaped version, it doesn't covert to html symbols, and I'm using charset="UTF-8" the code in html using JSX:

```
<h2>{classAbbreviation}</h2>
```

Comment: I think you can find you answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116800/how-to-show-html-entity-using-react

Comment: Thanks, it worked in case I know the symbol used, but if the user insert another symbol there is no way I can convert the HTML entities