# How to render HTML entity in React without dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: html, reactjs, unicode, font-awesome

I'm using custom fonts in my site, similar to Font Awesome, which have simple signature:

```
<i className="icon-plus"></i>
```

But I want to create own component which will be render dynamic HTML entities like:

```
const iconEntity = '&#xf2b9;' // (Font Awesome HTML entity example)
const icon1 = '&#xf13d;' // dynamic entities

class OwnIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <i>{iconEntity}</i>
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909134/nbsp-jsx-not-working) I trier using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and it works, e.g.:

```
const iconEntity = '&#xf2b9;'

class OwnIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <i className="icon" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: iconEntity }}></i>
  }
}
```

But it's a little bit ugly solution.
After reading [JSX gotchas](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.4.0-rc.3/docs/docs/02.3-jsx-gotchas.md#html-entities) I found that there are solutions like:

`A safer alternative is to find the unicode number corresponding to the entity and use it inside of a JavaScript string:`

```
<div>{'First \u00b7 Second'}</div>
<div>{'First ' + String.fromCharCode(183) + ' Second'}</div>
```

But how I could convert(for example, Font Awesome) Unicode Private-Use characters `"\f007"` or HTML hex entity`&#xf007` to get unicode number to get rid of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and render icons in more "clear" way?

Text examples: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vxx8xnz9j)

Comment: Why not use the same system as FA? Create classes for each entity with a `::before { content: >entity< }` and apply that class to your `<i />` tag?

Comment: For some reason requirements forced me for this solution without using pseudo elements, so I'm looking for the best way to render it as HTML hex entity.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a `Fragment` so the value becomes JSX, and will be output as HTML:

```
const iconEntity = <Fragment>&#xf2b9;</Fragment>

class OwnIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <i className="icon">{iconEntity}</i>
  }
}
```

The downside to this, of course, is that you don't get to say "Let's get dangerous!" like Darkwing Duck.  ;)