# JSX converts embedded variables as strings

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to dynamically generate some empty space based on an integer values.

I thought the following would work :

```
function createTab(level) {

    let y = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        y = y + " &nbsp; ";
    }

    let x = <span>{y}</span>;
    return x
}
```

However JSX renders this in quoting the y value within the span elements. The quoting is causing the **&nbsp** to be displayed as text.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml if you really need this feature. Sometimes rendering HTML directly is not a good idea, because of vulnerabilities.
React escapes strings before render by default.

Comment: hmmmm......so how do you make empty spaces in react?

Comment: Considering minimal changes in the code and my previous comment, the last part of function can be rewritten as `return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html=y} />`

Comment: Possibly this question is also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909134/nbsp-jsx-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I need to use the unicode character " \u00A0 " and it works :

```
function createTab(level) {

    let y = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        y = y + " \u00A0 ";
    }

    let x = <span>{y}</span>;
    return x
}
```

JSX doesn't seem to like HTML codes